# How to transfer DevExpress treelist value to memo when button is clicked?

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-7

How to transfer value to memo when button is clicked?

```
procedure Tnov_zam.cxdbtrlstclmnlst21cxDBTreeListColumn1PropertiesButtonClick(
  Sender: TObject; AButtonIndex: Integer);
begin
  mmo2.Lines.Add(lst21.DataController.DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName('Text_1').asstring);
end;`
```

doesn't work like that

I realized that when you click on the button in the treelist, the procedure is not even executed, what could be the reason for this?

Comment: I realized that when you click on the button in the treelist, the procedure is not even executed, what could be the reason for this?

Comment: Have you assigned the event handler in the Object Inspector panel? To add an event panel, it is not enough to add the code to the *.pas file -- you also need to assign the event handler in the *.dfm file (for instance, using the Object Inspector).